# ServiceStack: OrmLite and generic Insert<T> method returns weird number - not the PrimaryKey or any auto_increment

Tags: c#, primary-key, auto-increment, ormlite-servicestack

I have this POCO that I am adding to a db:

```
public class MyObject
{
    [ServiceStack.DataAnnotations.PrimaryKey]
    public long id { get; set; }
    public long alfaMessageId { get; set; }
    public long alfaNotificationId { get; set; }
    // bla bla bla
    public long responseToId { get; set; }
}
```

I then add such an object to the db (id is then 0 as the id is determined by the auto_increment), like this:

```
long id = dbWrite.Insert<MyObject>(alfaFrom);
```

The variable *long id* does not correspond to the auto_increment field 'id' in the table, it seems to be starting at 1 and the actual value of the 'id' is ignored completely.

I am using version 4.0.17.0 of OrmLite.

Comment: If `1` isn't the value in the database, it sounds like you've got a trigger running somewhere.

Comment: I am not using any triggers what so ever.

Comment: what is returned if you call `dbWrite.Insert<MyObject>(alfaFrom, true)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use GetLastInsertId() to get the, well, last inserted id.

Just looked at the source code, and it has this:

```
  internal static long Insert<T>(this IDbCommand dbCmd, T obj, bool selectIdentity = false)
        {
            OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.PrepareParameterizedInsertStatement<T>(dbCmd);

            OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.SetParameterValues<T>(dbCmd, obj);

            if (selectIdentity)
                return OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.InsertAndGetLastInsertId<T>(dbCmd);

            return dbCmd.ExecNonQuery();
        }
```

So if it keeps consistent with itself, I'd expect all inserts to return last inserted id. If you do see number of rows returned - I guess its not that consistent.

Comment: Well, I can (and I am), but that doesnt really answer my question: what is being returned by the .Insert<T>(...)?

Comment: @Ted, it's almost certainly the number of rows affected being returned.

Comment: I do "believe" it actually should return last inserted Id, I don't see what else it could meaningfully return, except maybe for number of rows inserted. In former, then something else is inserting after your insert. You're not sharing a connection with something else, right ?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud If its a long that method returns its almost certainly an id. If it were rows I'd expect an int - you're not likely to insert more that 2 billion rows at once, I'd say :)

Comment: @Eugene, that's a good train of thought; but I can't see it being anything else if you have no triggers.

Comment: It could be affected rows, cause it aint the id, thats for sure. And no, I an not sharing the connection with any other thread or so =)

Comment: default value of `selectIdentity` parameter is `false`.

Comment: @Ted Also another option is to use Db.Save() which auto populates the AutoIncrementing Id property.